# User Profile Data Not AutoPopulated into SP Custom List created through InfoPath Designer 2010

Tags: infopath, web-services, user-profile-service

I have created a custom list in sharepoint site and customzied the fields using the infopath designer 2010.I want the userprofile data to be loaded into SPList while click the new item after publishing the list into sharepoint site.

Steps Followed are

1. Created custom list from site actions from sharepoint site.
2. Customized the list
   List Settings-> Advanced Settings->
3. Created 4 mandatory fields with type "SINGLE LINE OF TEXT".
4. Now customized the list in Infopath designer and then Added the webservice to the list in infopath
5. WebService-> SOAP-> -> next->Selected GetUserProfileByName-> next-> finish.
6. On Form Load ->Condition-> AccountName=IsBlank
                 Rule -> Action-> Query for Data-> GetUserProfileByName.
7. Rules for all the fields with values mapped to ListService 
   Rule->Set fields value-> Empolyee'sName-> Advanced View-> GetUserProfileByName-> 
   Select Value-> Filter Data-> Insert Field or Group-> Set Fieldorgroup-isequalto->        TypeText="EmployeeName"
8. Done the Same to all the other fields and then published the list to SP2010.
9. Now when I add the new item UserProfile Data not autopopluated

Note- Service Started in CENTRAL ADMIN

Please help me out with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few steps. I assume you want to query the user profile service for the current user's data? To do this, you need to establish the current user name, then query the UserProfileByName connection. After that, you can copy the values.

Use the Form Load and create a rule with these actions:

1. Set one of your text fields to populate with the user account name, using the formula userName()
2. Set a field's value: Field to set is the GetUserProfileByName data source > Query Fields node > s0:GetUserProfileByName > AccountName. Set it to the value of the text field established in step 1.
3. Query GetUserProfileByName

Now you can copy the values to the text fields from the filtered Values field as you described above.

A very detailed article about querying the UPS in Infopath is available here: http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/